# New tag for the Micronaut Framework

Tags: feature-request, tags

Please create a tag for the "micronaut framework" (http://micronaut.io) - suggested tag: `micronaut` with a synonyme of `micronautfw`. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a question that _needs_ this tag? Since you have more than 1.5k rep, [you could create the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags), yourself.

Comment: From the Grails Community Slack: "Kindly create `micronaut` tag on stackoverflow (since it’s been officially announced). I have a lot of basic questions that I wanna ask about Graeme Rocher’s presentation and it’d be better to ask em there for better coverage and future reference."

Comment: _"Is there a question that needs this tag?"_ Tags can only be created by adding them to a question.

Comment: You learn something new everyday. Thank you @stijn